# Cannot convert String to Float error message when using CSV Reader

Tags: python

I am getting an error message "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'App'" when I try to use the csvreader module on python. The csv file has a mixture of strings and floats which I need to access later in my program. My code for reading the file is:

```py
csvreader = csv.reader(fileobj, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)  
next(csvreader, None) #skips the headers

for rows in csvreader:
    print(rows)
```

Below is a line from the csv file when printed without using the NON_NUMERIC add on.

```
['Parkinson Exercices FR', 'MEDICAL', '', '3', '1000', '0']
```

I have tried:

```
csvreader = csv.reader(fileobj, delimiter=",", escapechar="'")
```

Still get the same error though.

Comment: It looks like one of your rows contains a string where a float should be. Have you searched for that `App` string?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
line = []
with open(fileobj, newline='') as csvfile:
csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",", escapechar="'")
for row in csvreader:
    for item in row:
        try:
            line.append(float(item))
        except:
            line.append(str(item))
```

**line** return you a list something like this :
['string', 'string' , '...', float, ...]